# Having child processes printf to redirected stdout correctly

Tags: c, fork, stdout, child-process, freopen

I am redirecting `stdout` on a process with `freopen()`, and as long as it's just one process, everything's fine.

However, if I do something like this:

```
freopen("stdout.txt", "a+", stdout);
printf("Initial line.\n");

int i=0;
while(i<1000)
    {
        if(fork())
            wait(NULL);
        else
            printf("Line %d.\n", i);
        i++;
    }
```

The first printed lines are re-printed on the file over and over. Is there anything particular I should do to avoid this from happening?

Comment: Do you really want to create many thousands of processes? Think about the placement of that `fork` and what happens in the child processes *each iteration*.

Comment: `The first printed lines are re-printed on the file over and over` What do you mean by that? How does it get "re-printed"? Could give an example?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes

Comment: @KamilCuk Children of `fork()` also inherent everything else, like `stdout`, because the child is mostly a 1:1 copy of the parrent. I think you mixing up `fork()` and `exec()`

Comment: This code will create 2**1000-1 children, are you sure you want that? maybe you forgot an `exit()` in the child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first printed lines are re-printed on the file over and over.

This is because the standard C library applies *buffering* to the standard output stream when using `stdio` functions. In particular, when `stdout` is redirected to a file, the buffering mode changes from line-buffered to fully buffered (with a buffer of size defined by the library). In line-buffered mode, the buffer gets flushed (and the data actually written) only when a newline is encountered, *but* in fully buffered mode this only happens when the maximum buffer size is reached.

When you create multiple processes, they all share the same buffer of the parent. Since you do not reach the end of the buffer before spawning new children, and you do not empty it, they will all have the same buffer content. After that, when each of the children dies, the buffer will be automatically flushed by the standard library.

> Is there anything particular I should do to avoid this from happening?

Yes. Flush the buffer before creating children.

```c
freopen("stdout.txt", "a+", stdout);
printf("Initial line.\n");
fflush(stdout);

// ...
```

You also probably want to `exit()` before the next cycle after the child has done its job:

```c
int i=0;
while(i<1000)
{
    if(fork()) {
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        printf("Line %d.\n", i);
        exit(0);
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Before each `fork`? Or only once?

Comment: @Jim yes, basically before each `fork()`. If after any `printf()` you want to fork, you have to make sure to `fflush()` first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I realized there was something else I was doing. I wasn't exiting the child process and the counter was being incremented in the child process only, so the output was being messed up anyway. If you want, edit your code to take this into account so I can accept your answer!

Comment: @Jim well... not that I could know that, but sure, done.